# SWIG memory issue of allocating array inside a struct

Tags: python, c, swig

Suppose I have a C struct like this

```
struct foo {
    int sz;
    struct bar **arr;
};
```

In my SWIG file, I use "carrays.i" to give me control of the array inside this struct. Here I use

```
%module mdl
%include "carrays.i"
%array_functions(struct bar*, barArray)
```

Then I allocate memory for this array in python.

```
a = mdl.foo()
a.arr = mdl.new_barArray(sz)
```

My question is, should I free the memory of the allocated array by calling

```
mdl.delete_barArray(a.arr)
```

before I exit the current function, or SWIG will automatically do this for me so I don't need to worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call delete when the array is no longer needed.  If you don't do it before the `foo` object reference count goes to zero and is destroyed, you have a memory leak.